# Adding pop-up with info to <p:column> with selectionMode attribute

Tags: html, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a table similiar to this from primefaces showcase (second table - multiple selection with checkboxes):
http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableRowSelectionRadioCheckbox.jsf

I'd like to add a little pop-up box (similiar to HTML title attribute) with info when I hover over one of the auto-generated checkboxes (the one in the header which selects all others). Checkboxes are generated by this line of code:

```
<p:column selectionMode="multiple" style="width:2%" />
```

Code above creates column with checkbox rows. Header row is a special checkbox which selects all other checkboxes. I want to add a onhover message like "clicking this will select all checkboxes" for example.

I've tried the following but nothing works:

- `title` attribute from HTML
- `<p:toolkit>` tag
- `<p:overlayPanel>` tag (the problem is it should be used on some elements inside p:column, for example text, but in my case there is no content in p:column - just generated checkbox)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it on my own.

1. I created a div outside of `<p:dataTable>` (in my case: on top of the page)
2. I styled said div similiar to default pop-up when using `title="..."` attribute. I also added `position:absolute` and `display:none`.
3. I added jQuery script which keeps track of mouse coordinates and then when mouse is over checkbox uses them as `top` and `left` attributes of div and changes said div display to `block`. It causes div to appear near mouse cursor on checkbox hover.

It is also important to know that in primefaces the checkbox specified by me in question has always class named `ui-chkbox-all`

Here's the code:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="test">TEST</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#test 
{
    border: 1px #767676 solid;
    color: #767676;
    padding: 2px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: white;
    width: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
}
```

**JAVASCRIPT/JQUERY:**

```
var mouseX;
var mouseY;

$(document).mousemove( function(e) {
    mouseX = e.pageX - 80;
    mouseY = e.pageY - 80;
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".ui-chkbox-all").mouseenter(function(){
        $("#test").css("display", "block");
        $("#test").css({'top':mouseY,'left':mouseX}).fadeIn('slow');
    });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".ui-chkbox-all").mouseleave(function(){
        $("#test").fadeOut('slow');
    });
});
```